# passport renewal but not received

Tags: international-travel, pakistani-citizens, passport-renewals

I have applied for renewal of my Pakistani Passport, but I did not receive it yet. On other hand I also book my ticket for Pakistan, in case I don't receive my new passport before the date of travel, can I travel with my old passport that has a FRESH PASSPORT APPLIED stamp given while renewal and it is valid till November.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Timatic](https://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html) is the database used by airlines to determine who may board a flight, by indicating to the airline what documents are necessary to be admitted to the destination country. If you don't have that document or documents, the airline won't board you because they think you will be refused entry.

Entering your information (Pakistani citizen, flying to Pakistan), Timatic says that you must possess a valid Pakistani passport.  If your passport will still be valid upon your scheduled arrival back in Pakistan, the airline should allow you to board the flight. We don't know if this is so because you didn't say when your flight will occur.

If your passport will expire before the flight's scheduled arrival, however, the airline may refuse boarding. They would do this because an expired passport marked FRESH PASSPORT APPLIED is not the same as having a currently-valid passport.

Comment: @simonatrcl Thanks! On rereading carefully, I see that the OP is indeed talking about returning to Pakistan. My first-written answer addresses flying from Pakistan, and is inapposite. I have amended the Answer.

Comment: My old passport is not expired yet but when I applied for renewal they put the FRESH PASSPORT APPLIED stamp on it.. My departure date is July 20, 2019 and passport will expire on November 10, 2019.